# При установке ChromeDriver появляется такое сообщение, как быть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, chromedriver

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой при установке ChromeDriver: 
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Не знаю проблема это или нет, но при запуске кода Python, браузер не открывается:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: Может стоит добавить вызов `main()` в конец текста? ;)

Comment: Решил вопрос? У меня такая же проблема